# Rails - How to show validation errors on a shared form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm making a form that is reusable in multiple pages. Users can send an email with this form and the message it self get saved in the database.

I have two simple validations on this form, and the errors are getting displayed well with this form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @message do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :email, error: "E-mail can't be empty" %>
    <%= f.input :text, error: "Text can't be empty" %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

If I want my form to be reusable on multiple pages than I need to change it to:

```
<%= simple_form_for Message.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :email, error: "E-mail can't be empty" %>
    <%= f.input :text, error: "Text can't be empty" %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

The form and validation still work with this form, but it doesn't show the errors. I hope that someone can help me with this.

Comment: Why can't you use the first version of the form? The second version will never show any errors because it's always dealing with a fresh instance of `Message`

Comment: Because if I use `@message` somewhere else than the `new` page. It will crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to have a method in `ApplicationController` that creates the `@message` variable and then you just call it on every action you need to show the form.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # ..
  def load_message_for_form
    if params[:message]
      @message = Message.new(message_params)
    else
      @message = Message.new
    end
  end

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:email, :text) # add what you need
  end
end
```

and then in the actions you need the form

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_message_for_form, only: [:index, :new] #change this to suit your needs
end
```

EDIT:
While this solution indeed works very well, one should be careful not to overuse it, because `ApplicationController` would very soon be overcluttered with stuff like this. But for simple situations it's OK.

Comment: Yes it works indeed, but really be careful not to go overboard with solutions like these. If you find yourself putting to much stuff into application_controller, you have to rethink your solution a bit. But for simple situations it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, that you need the invalid object after validation to show the errors.

Using a shared form normally means, that you want to be able to show a form for creation of an instance of some model anywhere you like.
That's what your second form is good for.
That's why you use `Message.new`.

Now if some validations fails, your controller needs to redisplay the form with this invalid instance.
This can only be done with the first variant of your form.

So how can you redisplay the correct form?

- display the normal "new" view when an error occures when saving. This ripps your new object out of the contenxt where it was first embedded, but may be a good approach
- handle the submit of your shared form with AJAX and replace the shared form with the response of your controller, which is some "OK" in case of success or the first variant of your form in case of an error.

The second means something like:

```
<%= simple_form_for Message.new, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :email, error: "E-mail can't be empty" %>
  <%= f.input :text, error: "Text can't be empty" %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

then you need an js handler for the create action, that replaces the form: app/views/messages/new.js.erb

```
$('.new_message').html('<%= escape_javascript render partial: 'form' %>');
```

And for success: app/views/messages/create.js.erb:

```
$('.new_message').html('Got your message!');
```

In your controller, you need to handle js requests:

```
  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.save
        format.html { redirect_to @message, notice: 'Message was successfully created.' }
        format.js 
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.js { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
```

This leaves all of the code in the context of the message.
You don't taint `ApplicationController` and other controllers, where you want to include the shared form.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I will defiantly give it a try!

Comment: So I tried it out and I worked quite well, and I like this approach. It show's the invalid instance of the message, but the validation errors that I used to have won't show up anymore. Any idea if it's possible to show these? Would be nice if they show up in the same way as they use do. (It was done by simple_form + bootstrap)